# How to compare on Scala enumerations Value-type?

Tags: scala, enums

Consider this:

```
import packageName.doType._

class Worker
{
    def doSomething(doType: DoType): Unit =
    {
        if(doType == Default) //...
    }
}
```

Same file

```
object DoType extends Enumeration
{
  type DoType = Value
  val Default, Special = Value
}
```

Now as soon as I added the `if(doType == Default)` line I get two errors:

"==" cannot be resolved and suddenly "Value" in the `DoType` is not found anymore -.-

How can I check on the actual value of doType? I can solve the same very easily with (case-)classes, but I wanted to do it with enumerations.

**edit:** I already know that one cannot do pattern-matching on the type as it is a `def` and no `val`, still: How would you do this then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
def doSomething(doType: DoType): Unit
```

IMHO it should be:

```
def doSomething(doType: DoType.Value): Unit
```